# Renaming the Package Name inside an APK

Tags: android, package, apk, rename

I have created an **AIR app** that is currently on the market. To update the app, obviously I must keep the same package name. My first version's were packaged using **Eclipse** with the ADT plugin.

Now to use **AIR 3.0 Native Extensions** (ANE) which were not available when I first developed the app, I currently must create my APK using AIR's command line tools. Unfortunately, these command line tools force you to have a package name that starts with the word "air". For example, I need the package name "com.example". AIR creates the package name as "air.com.example".

So now, I cannot update my app in the market since the package name has changed. Adobe has this horrific article to help you rename and remove the "air" in the package. I'm not a great programmer so this has really stumped me.
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/875/cpsid_87562.html

Apparently this info is out of date or incorrect in a few areas.
I have completely stumbled at step 12 which uses **apkbuilder**:

```
 apkbuilder final.apk -u -z resources.arsc -f classes.dex
```

I am getting this error message:

*THIS TOOL IS DEPRECATED. See --help for more information.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: **resources.arsc** does not exist*

I have used step 10 to create the new **resources.arsc** file. It clearly DOES exist and in the correct location. I tried using apkbuilder with other resources.arsc files taken from other projects. I still get the same error message.

Is there a chance in hell of this working? If anyone is interested in this, I have a zip file with a sample AIR apk, windows bat files for all the command line work, and all the needed utilities so they don't need to be downloaded. To get started you just need to change my path.bat to fit your system. And you need notepad++ (or an equivalent) to batch automate renaming the package name across several files.
[bradwallacedesign.com/dktimer/renameApkProject.zip](http://bradwallacedesign.com/dktimer/renameApkProject.zip)

Thanks so much!

Comment: To add onto brad51's response, for those who do not have a keystore but only a .p12 file (working in Flash), here's a helpful article on converting: http://aleksmaus.blogspot.com/2012/01/android-application-signing-with-pkcs12.html Also, I didn't have errors about files not being moved over.

Comment: In addition this link was very helpful in creating the keystore: http://www.mobilefish.com/tutorials/java/java_quickguide_keytool.html

Answer (score 9):

this was done on a pc. i have no idea how to do this on a mac.

i don't recommend using this to remove the "air." from an air package name. If you do so, the user will not be prompted to download air on their device. the user will get an error message instead with no clue to the problem. of course you can use air captive runtime to solve this issue.

http://bradwallacedesign.com/share/renameAPK.zip

download and unzip my file (renameAPK.zip) to c:\renameAPK.

### required files:

1. my file (renameAPK.zip) which contains the apkTool
2. java jdk/jre
3. android SDK
4. notepad++ (or an equivalent text editor that can rename across multiple files)

i made many bat files since i'm not sure how to combine them into one file. you will need to edit each one to change your path names and file names to work with your computer and your apk file.

i numbered all the bats in the order that i use them. once a command line is open, i type the number of the bat file i want then hit the tab key to automatically finish the name of the bat file then hit enter to run that bat file.

### instructions:

double click **`openCmd.bat** to open a command line pointing to the directory with all your files.

**0.**  run **0path.bat** to set your path. (i can't remember now if the adobe air sdk is needed for this but i have it in my path. obviously, the JDK is needed and the android sdk for the jarsigner and zip align i think.)

**1.** run **1decompileAPK.bat** to have apkTool decompile your app into a folder called UNZIPPEDapk

**2.** follow the instructions in **2editManifest & PackageName - Instructions (not a bat).txt** to edit the manifest and package name using Notepad++ inside UNZIPPEDapk:

edit AndroidManifest.xml:

**a.** change package name from air.oldPackageName to newPackageName

**b.** edit other needed entries:

**c.** rename folder system inside "smali" folder so that it works with your new package name
   for example:
      if the old package name was: air/oldName then change the folders to match the new package name: air/newName

use **notepad++** (or any editor that can find and replace text over many files)

---

**d.** ctrl+shift+f --- "Find in files"

```
  find:
air/oldPackageName
  replace with:
newPackageName
  where:
all files in UNZIPPEDapk/smali
```

(i think there were over 200 replacements)

**3.** run **3buildDistFolder.bat** to have apkTool build the new apk in the UNZIPPEDapk\Dist folder

**4.** follow the instructions in **4getMissingFiles - instructions.txt** to reinstate the 2 missing files in the new build:

**a.** Two files were not built during 3buildDistFolder:

3buildDistFolder.bat built the new apk in the \UNZIPPEDapk\dist folder but it failed to copy 2 files:

```
(skipping hidden file 'C:\Users\computer\apkTool\UNZIPPEDapk\assets\META-INF
```

\AIR\extensions\com.adobe.mobile\META-INF\ANE\Android-ARM.classpath')
    (skipping hidden file 'C:\Users\computer\apkTool\UNZIPPEDapk\assets\META-INF
\AIR\extensions\com.adobe.mobile\META-INF\ANE\Android-ARM.project')

grab these 2 files from your original apk and drop them into your new apk in the correct folder

**b.** copy yourApp.apk from   DKTimer/Dist/   to root directory where your bat files are.

**5.** run **5signAPK.bat** to sign the apk.

developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

**6.** run **6verifySigned.bat** to verify the signing worked properly

**7.** run **7zipAlign.bat** to align the apk file.

developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/zipalign.html

---

You are finished at this point. Continue on if you want to test it on a device.

**8.** run **8installAPK.bat** to install the apk on a usb connected device.

**9.** run **9remoteDebugger.bat** if you want to use remote debugging.

---

i hope this helps someone. let me know if i forgot to include something.
also, if you know a better way to do this, please comment (such as how to combine this into 1 long pausing bat file...)

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple environment variable you can set to disable the `air.` prefix easily.  The following code exists in the Adobe AIR packager:

```
String optOut = System.getenv("AIR_NOANDROIDFLAIR");
if ((optOut == null) || (optOut.indexOf("true") == -1)) {
  packageName = "air." + packageName;
}
```

So, simply set the `AIR_NOANDROIDFLAIR` environment variable to `true`, repackage your application, and it won't have the `air.` prefix.  Google how to set environment variables in [windows](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20set%20environment%20variables) or [mac](https://www.google.com/search?q=mac%20set%20environment%20variables) for your particular OS version.

For example, I use the command-line compiler on Mac/Linux, so I run:

```
> export AIR_NOANDROIDFLAIR=true
> java -jar $AIR_HOME/lib/adt.jar -package -target apk-captive-runtime -storetype pkcs12 -keystore cert.p12 -storepass *** Main.apk Main-app.xml Main.swf
```

Warning: I don't know what implications this has.  Per someone's note above, this may only be a good idea with captive runtime (but that's the default going forward from AIR 3.8).

*Update:* Renaun Erickson [said](https://plus.google.com/u/0/103202870591954554318/posts/RVqFVm6FT55) it shouldn't cause problems.

Cross-posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218641/renaming-the-package-name-inside-an-apk/16593989#16593989) (slightly different question, same answer).

Comment: Hey jeff, I pretty much get the idea of what you're doing. But not not sure where I go to actually type out 'export AIR_NOANDROIDFLAIR=true' I've been googling this like crazy but I'm still not understanding how to go about this approach. I'm starting to think maybe I need to create some .plist file? But where? Is the only thing I type in the file 'export AIR_NOANDROIDFLAIR=true'? Mind explaining where I set this? Sorry, just stuck fixing this because I'm switching to AIR from an old app developed with native android. I hate Adobe for this.

Comment: @brybam - indeed, I don't know my way around OSX well enough to set permanent environment variables that will work from the GUI.  But surely the info is out there.  Sorry!

Comment: Wow, if it was this easy, why did Adobe have this over-complicated multi-step process explained at their site, which involved editing and repackaging the APK? (I think it was 12 steps or more!)

Answer (score 5):

Having tried several apkRename tools, I found that they all failed for some app, such as com.android.browser on HTC device.

The reason is in apktool which does not correctly unpack apk file sometimes.

---

So, i create my own tool: https://github.com/sjitech/ApkRename
No need apktool, no need aapt, just java and jar utilities.
This utility directly modify AndroidManifest.xml so without recompile whole resource by apktool,
so it's clean.

Tested devices: 11 kinds (both android 4+, but 2.2+ should be no OK)
Tested OS: Mac OS X 10.9 and CentOS 6. (Cygwin with bash 4+ should be OK, but not tested yet)

Answer (score 1):

I actually tried brad's approach and couldn't imagine having to go through the process EVERY TIME i compiled a release. so i did something else...i modified ADT so it doesn't insert "air." at the start and replaces it with a more useful extension like "com."

Here's a summary of the approach:

use: 
jar xf adt.jar

to extract the adt.jar file to a directory on your desktop. you'll find it in {adobe SDK}/lib/

look for the file APKOutputStream.class

com/adobe/air/apk/APKOutputStream.class

Open it in a hex editor (eg, HxD is what i used). Search for "air." (without the quotes but including the dot).

Don't delete the entry. i tried, you can't, it corrupts the class and it won't run. What you can do, however, is replace "air." with "com." because it has the same number of characters and doesn't mess with the length of the file. The com prefix is a lot more useful to most of us.

save the modified APKOutputStream.class file and repackage with JAR. something like this:

jar cfm ..\patchedadt.jar ..\MANIFEST.MF *

you'll want to copy that MANIFEST.MF file from the subdirectory of the package called META-INF

Rename your patchedadt.jar to adt.jar and put it back in the lib directory. Works with the Flash Builder and all that garb.

Needless to say, when you're in there, you'll want to produce your package without a "com." prefix so you don't end up with com.com.your.package.name.

maybe there was an easier way, but i didn't know any better and no one else had an answer except to decompile the apk, modify it, and recompile and that didn't even work. so i figured i'll share what i did in case someone else stumbles on it later :)

jim

Comment: nice solution, i followed it.

Comment: @jim - clever solution!  I'm not sure if you've seen my answer yet, but there's an environment variable setting built into ADT so you can easily disable the `air.` prefix.