# Remove air prefix from adobe air applications

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, prefix

A lot of people facing this problem and I got the solution here at adobe [link](http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/opt-out-air-application-analytics.html)
However I got stuck at the sixth step of setting up the environment variables on windows. Is the path given there correct? I have my sdk and apktool downloaded to my d drive. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android App ID prefix problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163561/android-app-id-prefix-problem)

Comment: Bhaijaan - don't use Adobe's lengthy instructions, see my answer on the above link.  You only have to set one environment variable to make the compiler remove the "air." prefix.

Comment: Yes I saw your answer but brother I could not understand it properly. This is my first try at making android apps with air. Can you please explain where do I put that code String optOut = System.getenv("AIR_NOANDROIDFLAIR");
if ((optOut == null) || (optOut.indexOf("true") == -1)) {
  packageName = "air." + packageName;
}

Comment: using windows by the way.

Comment: Search for "how to set environment variable in windows".  Create a new environment variable with the name `AIR_NOANDROIDFLAIR` and value `true` - then run your package step and you should get an apk file without the `air.` prefix.